# Bluetooth device immidiently disconnects

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect a module named HC05 to my Ubuntu 20.04 but when it connects, after 1 or 2 seconds it disconnects. I also installed a Bluetooth manager. When I try to connect with manager, it pairs but does not connect. Does anyone have this problem before?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnmsP.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I added output.